# Removing cloned nodes from list

Tags: c#, clone, deep-copy

I am making a filtereditems class, that will be displayed as a treeview in WPF. The filtereditems class contains only certain node items from a treeitems class that contain certain criteria. I am able clone all of the tree items and add them to the filtereditems list. From there I find nodes that do not meet the criteria and remove them appropriately. However I have found that using the clones renders me unable to remove these items. Is there something I should know about cloned items and why they can't be removed from my collection?

```
public class Node: INotifyPropertyChanged, ICloneable
{
    public Name { get;set;}
    public ID {get;set;}
    public ParentNode {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Nodes> ChildNodes{get;set;}
    public object Clone() 
        {
            Node toReturn = new Node();
            toReturn.Name = this.Name;
            toReturn.ID = this.ID;
            toReturn.ParentNode = this.ParentNode;
            foreach (Node child in this.ChildNodes)
            {
                toReturn.ChildNodes.Add((Node) child.Clone());
            }
            return toReturn;
        }
 }

 public void filterStart(ChildNodesListViewDataSource _filterStart)
        {
            if (this.FilterString != null && this.Entity != null)
            {
                this.TotalItemsNumber = 0;
                this.FilterItemsNumber = 0;

                    this.FilterTreeItems.Clear();
                    foreach (Node y in TreeItems)
                    {

                        this.FilterTreeItems.Add((Node)y.Clone());
                        foreach (Node x in FilterTreeItems)
                        {
                            FilterRoot(x);
                        }
                    }

                TakeOutTrash();

public bool FilterRoot(Node FilterItems)
        {
            bool HasMatchingChildren = false;
            if (FilterItems.ChildNodes != null ||        FilterItems.ChildNodes.Count !=0)
            {
                foreach (Node FilterItemsComponenents in FilterItems.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (FilterRoot(FilterItemsComponenents))
                    {
                        HasMatchingChildren = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            string NameOfFilterItem = FilterItems.Name.ToUpper();
            string FilterStringUpperCase = FilterString.ToUpper();
            bool FilterStringCheck = NameOfFilterItem.Contains(FilterStringUpperCase);
            if (!FilterStringCheck && !HasMatchingChildren)
            {
                trimIDs.TrashCan.Add(FilterItems);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

public void TakeOutTrash()
        {
            foreach (Node node in trimIDs.TrashCan)
            {
                this.FilterTreeItems.Remove(node);
            }
        }

        public class TrimIDs
        {
            public IList<ComponentNodeViewModel> TrashCan { get; set;}
            {
                TrashCan = new List<ComponentNodeViewModel>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you cloning them?

Comment: Put your code please and clarify your problem

Comment: I am cloning them because the TreeItems and FilterTreeItems classes are both pointers and due to the way these classes were created removing nodes is the simplest way to filter the tree. However all of the logic works for filtering except in the TakeOutTrash method I am unable to actually Remove(node). Even though my code reaches this method.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my issue by creating another clone method that clones anything Node that is not in the List of Nodes not to clone: (Hope this helps anyone that was in my same predicament).

```
public object Clone(IList<Node> ListNotToClone)
    {
        NodetoReturnFiltered = new Node();
        toReturnFiltered.Name = this.Name;
        toReturnFiltered.ID = this.ID;
        toReturnFiltered.ParentNode= this.ParentNode;
        foreach (Node child in this.ComponentNodes)
        {
            if (!ListNotToClone.Contains(child))
            {
                toReturnFiltered.ComponentNodes.Add((Node)child.Clone(ListNotToClone));
            }
        }
        return toReturnFiltered;
    }
```

I then used this method :

```
public void TakeOutTrash()
    {
        foreach (ComponentNodeViewModel root in this.FilterTreeItems)
        {
            FilterHolder = (ComponentNodeViewModel)root.Clone(trimIDs.TrashCan);
        }
    }
```

And passed FilterHolder back into FilterTreeItems in the FilterStart method,

```
this.FilterTreeItems.Clear();
this.FilterTreeItems.Add(FilterHolder);
```